# Google Closure - Import Legacy Class in ES6 Module Class

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I have a code base written using ES5, and I want to update just part of the code to ES6 using Modules.
This is the code I have:

```
goog.module('farm.animal.Cow');

// Legacy class using es5
var Animal = goog.require('namespace.Animal');

class Cow extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

exports = Cow;
```

and this is the legacy class

```
goog.provide('namespace.Animal');

namespace.Animal = function() {

};
```

I tried to follow the migration recommendations on the GitHub Wikis of both projects:

https://github.com/google/closure-library/wiki/goog.module:-an-ES6-module-like-alternative-to-goog.provide

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Migrating-from-goog.modules-to-ES6-modules

but no luck so far. Most of the time I get the following error:

```
depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace "namespace.Animal" never provided.
```

Does anyone have any idea about how should be the proper way to migrate the code? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No one uses Google Closure, neither you should. The world moves forward, and some technologies die overtime while some others continue to live. Google Closure is still used & updated by Google itself, but probably no one else.

Comment: Even though Google Closure might not be a sound choice in 2019 if you would write new code, this does not mean that there do not exist legacy code bases written in it! It does not mean this question is invalid.

Comment: @evilReiko untrue, every single Clojurescript app uses it under the hood.

Comment: @evilReiko I understand the popularity angle, but as far as I know, nothing offers as sophisticated optimization as Google Closure does yet, so while it is not popular, it ought to be, or something just as good needs to come around.